# Phpseclib SSH2 - How to Suppress Sudo Prompt output on Exec

Tags: php, bash, ssh, sudo, phpseclib

Been wrestling with this one for a little bit. I'm currently working on a PHP application that connects to a custom API as well as performs changes to a server via Phpseclib's SSH2 library.

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($server_name);

if(!$ssh->login("username", "password")) {
   $result['result'] = 'ERROR';
   $result['message'] = 'Login failed';
} else {
   $result['propertyFolderDeleted'] = $ssh->exec("cd /var/www/sites; echo 'password' | sudo -S /usr/local/bin/delete_property.sh -sc $company_name -sp $property_name");

   return '{"data":'.json_encode($result).'}';
}
```

**Output generated:**

```
{"data":{"propertyFolderDeleted":"[sudo] password for portals: "}}
```

Pretty straight-forward, my application uses SSH2 to `exec` some Bash scripts I have in place on my server. For the most part this works flawlessly, but for some reason, `exec`-uting this one Bash script ('delete_property.sh') outputs the sudo password prompt as a result. 
I've tweaked my request and executing my Bash script via command-line (in Putty) no longer outputs the prompt text upon completion of the Bash script.

Why isn't this the case when using Phpseclib?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the user to the sudorious file.

1. Open the terminal.
2. Type "sudo visudo"
3. Add at the end of the file "youruser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" and just replace "youruser" with your real user.
4. Save and exit.

Now every one command with your user which is using sudo will be executed without asking the password.